# ipmi open sol, but the remote console cannot be displayed

Tags: console, ipmi

[SOL Session operational.  Use ~? for help]

Keep telling me this. How do we solve it?

ipmitool -I lanplus -H $ip -U $username -P $passwd sol deactivate

How to solve it? Did a lot of digging and didn't find anything relevant.